# How to resolve "server could not bind to the transport \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_<UUID> because another computer on the network has the same name" errors?

Tags: windows, windows-11, event-viewer

What is the meaning of the below event viewer error and how to resolve it?

> The server could not bind to the transport
> \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{645D56E9-F6B3-44C1-B7C9-B5A0503A76ED} because
> another computer on the network has the same name.  The server could
> not start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 machines with the same hostname.

Comment: I did check the local network but it doesnt have other machines with the same name. I have a few VMs running on the same host machine where this error came up but even those havent been named the same.

Comment: Are those VMs cloned from each other and/or happen to share e.g. the MAC or use the host interface directly?

Comment: No just docker on WSL2. I believe they must be sharing one of the virtual NICs

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with a brand-new laptop (windows 11 home). I've recently renamed the laptop and it's still happening. This is a home network and there are only 3 active computers at the moment, and names are definitely different.

Comment: I searched in regedit and it is related to a VMnetAdapter (from vmware) found in  `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{645D56E9-F6B3-44C1-B7C9-B5A0503A76ED}\x` where x is a sequential number (identifier). If you don't need vmware, uninstalling it could help or disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP on your vmware adapters.

Answer (score 4):

Check all your network adapters (under Settings>Network & internet>Advanced network settings) and see if there is a network device, created by some application, that is no longer needed. Delete that network device (Disabled is not enough) using Computer-Manage (Uninstall and also remove driver). I had a similar problem, when trying to connect to a VPN using FortiClient. That error message - EventId 2505 appear. Until I've figured it out, I run command ipconfig /registerdns in order to connect to see the VPN network (after running the command the LAN network start to respond after a around 90 seconds). After clean the unnecessary network adapter, problem was solved. Operating system: Windows 11 Pro Workstation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me this came when i bought a new computer and couldn't connect to my 5Ghz wifi (ASUS RT-AC51U). This was the only error i got anywhere. (The server could not bind to the transport \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{xxx} because another computer...)

Took a long time testing all sorts of things. In the end, I renamed my computer (even tho there were no devices sharing the name..) AND renamed it from my wifi router's DHCP list to the newly assigned name. After renaming it from the router, i was able to connect to the 5ghz network and everything worked! Woo!

I also disabled netbios over tcp from both network adapters prior to this that didn't have any effect tho until the name changes so not sure if disabling netbios had any part in this.

As mentioned, my problem was ONLY on the 5ghz wifi. 2,4ghz worked fine (but 2,4 is sh*t). I upgraded to win 11, updated every firmware and driver there is, changed every setting imaginable and just couldn't connect. But in the end, renaming the pc + tell it to the router was all i needed to do... i guess it used my old computer's DHCP lease (different name, different mac address) and got confused.